Altering CKEditor Version 4 to include Upload Image
The library for CKEDITOR in flask is only updated to version 4. Which i believe is fine for my purposes.
The desired result is to add the image2 option to the CKEDITOR. Below is my current Javascript but i am not seeing the desired result.
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="content" class="form-label">Content</label>
{{ form.content(class="form-control", id="content") }}
</div>

<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/upload',
    extraPlugins: 'uploadimage,image2',
    removeDialogTabs: 'image:advanced;link:advanced',
    height: 300,  // Adjust the height of the editor
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'document', items: ['Source'] },  // Add source editing
        { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
        { name: 'styles', items: ['Format'] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
        { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'] }
    ]
});


// Sync CKEditor content with the hidden textarea before form submission
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    for (const instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
});

Anticipated comments:

label = content but replace = editor.
a. not sure why but when change the replace = content i do not see the input box at all.


